# Duplicated result in hibernate because of inner join: how to solve?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this table:

```
TABLE1
ID PRIMARY KEY
FIELD1
```

and this table:

```
TABLE2
T1_ID REFERENCES TABLE1(ID),
FIELD1,
PRIMARY KEY(T1_ID, FIELD1)
```

so, the primary key of the first table is part of the primary key of the second table (and also an external reference).

I tried modeling it in this way in hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Table1 {

    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id; //easy!

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Table2> references;
 }
```

For the table2 I first created the key:

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Table2Key{

@Column(name= "T1_ID")
private String t1Id;

@Column(name = "FIELD1")
private Long field1;
```

Then I use it:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Table2 {

@EmbeddedId
private Table2Key id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "T1_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ToString.Exclude
private Table1 table1;
```

For some reason, when I want to fetch the elements of the first entity I get:

```
select * from TABLE1 t1
 inner join TABLE2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.T1_ID
```

And this leads to a list of duplicates entities of type T1!
What am I doing wrong?

**edit**
Following some advices I tried to change the List into a Set:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "table2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Table2> references;
```

But now I get like an **infinite loop** when retrieving the references objects: hibernate keeps selecting objects from the Table2!

```
select * from Table2 where T1_ID =?
```

Comment: If the answer doesn't help, it is worth adding data in your table to your question

Comment: Data is the same, I checked field by field...I'm getting crazy

Answer (score 1):

- I don't see an issue in your original post except that Id types `Long` and `String` are mapped wrong way around `Table2Key`. It should be

```
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class Table2Key {

      @Column(name= "T1_ID")
      private Long t1Id;

      @Column(name = "FIELD1")
      private String field1;

    }
```

- If it is still an issue and if you inserted the data manually into your application, I will delete all the data and will store the data via `spring-data-jpa` repository methods.
- As I mentioned, you have incorrect data in your database. Here is a sample app with exact entities as yours. It inserts data and then do a find all without any duplicates

  - https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoveflow-63040676

Comment: well. Can you delete the data and save it via repo. I assume you inserted the data manually?

Comment: no it belongs to an existing db and I can't do that

Comment: See the sample repo that works without any issues and issues the right queries